# How can I create a angular app that can subscribe to push notifications from a drupal CMS?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, drupal, push

I'm using phonegap and angular to develop the native app. There are no user accounts. This is using local storage on the phone only. The app lets you subscribe to several different push notifications. The admin server that sends out these push notifications is a drupal site.

Is a third party service needed?

Comment: I'm looking to use drupal to push notifications to a phonegap ios and android app. There will be multiple notifications users can subscribe to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `$cordovaPush` http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/ cordova plugin, you can register to listen for push notifications.